How to indicate selection in a map marker in streamlit?
In streamlit, is it possible to indicate that a marker in a map has been selected?
For example, a map contains red dots indicating some places, the user clicks on them to select them, the clicked icons become blue indicating they have been selected. A list of selected cities is generated.
Or, the marker changes from one to another, any kind of indication would do, but I cannot find out how to do this.
thanks in advance
I am a beginner so I asked chat gpt for suggestions and none of the exemples actually worked.
